# Works with chrome but not safari (?<![\n])[\n]{1}(?![\n])

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this regex `(?<![\n])[\n]{1}(?![\n])` in my Javascript code, and as I understand Safari just doesn't support negative look behinds.

What I need to do is replace all \n that are not surrounded by other \n and replace them with a string.

Can someone please help me figure out how to write that Regex so that it is usable in Safari?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```js
text.replace(/(\n)?\n(?!\n)/g, function(p,q) {
    return q === undefined ? "<a string>":p
})
```

JS code:

```js
var text = "a\nb\n\nc"
console.log(
  text.replace(/(\n)?\n(?!\n)/g, function(p,q) {
    return q === undefined ? "<a string>":p
}))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could capture either the start of the string or a non whitespace character in group 1.

Then match a single newline, and assert not a newline to the right.

In the replacement use the capture group followed by your replacement string `$1[replacement]`

Note that you don't need the square brackets around the newline, and you can omit `{1}`

```
(\S|^)\n(?!\n)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sx1QwC/1)

```js
const regex = /(\S|^)\n(?!\n)/g;
const str = `
this is a
this is b
this is c

d


test

test


test
test
`;

const result = str.replace(regex,`$1[replacement]`);

console.log(result);
```

Your pattern with the lookbehind (if supported):

```js
const regex = /(?<!\n)\n(?!\n)/g;
const str = `
this is a
this is b
this is c

d


test

test


test
test
`;
`[replacement]`
const result = str.replace(regex,`[replacement]`);

console.log(result);
```